# File not found error, even though file was found

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using the following bit of code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(corpus_name):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".v4_gold_conll"):
            f= open(file)
            lines = f.readlines()
            tokens = [line.split()[3] for line in lines if line.strip() 
and not line.startswith("#")]
    print(tokens)
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "text_statistics.py", line
>   28, in 
>       corpus_reading_pos(corpus_name, option)   File "text_statistics.py", line 13, in corpus_reading_pos
>       f= open(file) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abc_0001.v4_gold_conll'

As you can see, the file was, in fact, located, but then when I try to open the file, it... can't find it?

Edit:
using this updated code, it stops after reading 7 files, but there are 172 files.

```
def corpus_reading_token_count(corpus_name, option="token"):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(corpus_name):
        tokens = []
        file_count = 0
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".v4_gold_conll"):
                with open((os.path.join(root, file))) as f:
                    tokens += [line.split()[3] for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith("#")]
                    file_count += 1
    print(tokens)
    print("File count:", file_count)
```

Comment: You find that file in `corpus_name`, but you are opening it in the current working directory.

Comment: So my corpus contains hundreds of files, I need to access only the files that end in ".v4_gold_conll" and extract the information. I'm not sure how I would go about that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file` is just the file without the directory, which is `root` in your code. Try this:

```
f = open(os.path.join(root, file)))
```

Also, you should better use `with` to open the file, and not use `file` as a variable name, shadowing the builtin type. Also, judging from your comment, you should probably extend the list of tokens (use `+=` instead of `=`):

```
tokens = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(corpus_name):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".v4_gold_conll"):
            with open(os.path.join(root, filename))) as f:
                tokens += [line.split()[3] for line in f if line.strip() and not line.startswith("#")]
print(tokens)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but after replacing this part, it only extracted the tokens from one file, and not all of the files??

Comment: Now I'm having a problem where it is stopping after having only opened 7 files. There should be 172 files in the folder and subfolders.

Comment: Well, there is no reason it should "stop" after seven files. Are you sure those files have the correct extension? Remember that files in Python are case-sensitive. What happens if you add an `else` to the `if`?

Comment: the files I am wanting to open all have the identical ending, ".v4_gold_conll". Does it make a difference that they're located within different subfolders and subsubfolders?

Comment: It looks like it's only reading the files that are in the very lowest subfolder, and none of the files in other subfolders.

Comment: @socrlax24 I think you have to move the initialization of `tokens` one more level up; see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to join the `root` with the filename.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(corpus_name):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".v4_gold_conll"):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file)) as f:
            tokens = [
                line.split()[3]
                for line in f
                if line.strip() and not line.startswith("#")
            ]
            print(tokens)
```